# RPi and Ultrasonic Sensor

Tags: python, pi-zero-w, sensor

I'm new to RPi and electronics and I have a following problem:
I'm trying to make app where I will count how many times a line is crossed. I'm using a Ultrasonic sensor with which I am measuring distance and when that distance is changed to smaller value the counter is increased by one. The code I have works good but only one strange thing happens. When nothing happens (there is no any movements in a room) sometimes sensor reads smaller value and increase counter so I don't have reliable information about how many times the line is crossed.
Here is the code:

```
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO_TRIGGER = 2
GPIO_ECHO = 3

GPIO.setup(GPIO_TRIGGER, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(GPIO_ECHO, GPIO.IN)
def distance():
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)
    time.sleep(1)

    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, True)
    time.sleep(0.00001)
    GPIO.output(GPIO_TRIGGER, False)

    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 0:
        pulse_start = time.time()
    while GPIO.input(GPIO_ECHO) == 1:
        pulse_end = time.time()

    pulse_duration = pulse_end - pulse_start

    distance = pulse_duration * 17150

    return round(distance, 2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        last_read = distance()
        count = 0
        while True:
            dist = distance()
            if (last_read - 50 > dist):
                print('DISTANCE: ' + str(dist))
                count += 1
                print(count)
                time.sleep(0.5)
            last_read = dist
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Measurement stopped by User')
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

I'm using RPi Zero W and I've connected Ultrasonic Sensor like this: Trig - pin 3, Echo - pin 5, Vcc - pin 4 and Gnd - pin 6.

I've tried experimenting with time.sleep() providing different values, also I have tried connecting sensor to Arduino Nano and with the same formula measure distance and print it but I  get same strange behavior when the room is empty.

The only thing, maybe stupid, that I can assume is because fridge in a room makes a little bit harder noise but I'm not sure. For example, when I start program I direct sensor to the wall and put it immobile, I print measured distance and it says about 205 cm, and when I leave room for some time and come back I can see that there is some points where sensor read some random values like 95cm, 110cm, 145cm etc.

Does someone have any other ideas why this could happen?

Comment: You need to improve your noise filtering.  The lower value showing up can be a function of natural occurrences in the room.  You need to figure out what the difference is between these and the real signal you want.  perhaps the real signal is at the lower value for several consecutive readings while the noise is not?

Comment: Problem is if I make delays between measurements the real signal is that shows maximum range (range to the wall) and also the real signal is anything between 0 and (max range - 50, as condition for counter increment is set like that), and if delay is for example 1s I get just one value if I put something in front of sensor, and also noises does not occour multiple times in a row. But nevermind, you gave me an idea what I could try, so thank you anyway for commenting. I'll put answer if idea gone work. :)